# lstm how to carry out walk forward validation & saving model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a LSTM model that has been trained. However I would like to now try doing a walk forward validation with my model & I'm a bit confused how to go about it.

Lets say that I use a years daily data (Jan 2010 to Dec 2010) to make some predictions about the next month (Jan 2011). Then once that month has completed I include the data from that month so my years worth of training data is now Feb 2010 to Jan 2011 which is used to make some predictions about Feb 2011.

So I have my trained model for Jan 2010 to Dec 2010. How do I then pass the final model weights to the next training batch (Feb 2010 to Jan 2011) so that it doesn't need to start again? Or should each time I train the model it begin with a random starting weight?

Is it simply something like calling the function below in a loop and somehow making use of the returned model? Can the model be saved at each training point so that it can be retrieved and checked later on?

```
 function train_model(X_train, y_train)

     model.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        batch_size=1024,
        epochs=50,
        validation_split=0.05)

    return model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to both questions.

1) Without recompiling the model the model weights are bound to in the model so

```py
# model  = train and fit model for Jan 2010 to Jan 2011
#
for X, y in batches: # batches over new window (Feb 2010 to Feb 2011)
    model.fit(X, y)
```

works to update the model from previous weights but do think about if this is exactly what you want to do.

2. Yes, saving and loading a model works as expected

```py
# weights model.get_weights()
# write weights  to disk 
... 
# weighs = read weights 
# model = load model architecture 
model.set_weights(weights)
```

Should do the trick.

For saving at checkpoints I'd recommend using the [ModelCheckpoint](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/) callback. That makes it easy to save the model and specific iterations points so that you can train from that point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use model checkpoint callbacks as follows: for example capture the maximum accuracy obtained so far and save it in the checkpoint file.

```
checkpoint_filepath = '/tmp/checkpoint'
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
                 filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
                 monitor='val_acc',
                 mode='max',
                 save_best_only=True)
```

and then fit the model. 
`model.fit(epochs=10, callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])`
you can reload it again for update. 
`model.load(checkpoint_filepath)`